# guardar un arreglos en java

Tags: java

Buenas noches amigos, soy nuevo en esto, me dejaron hacer un codigo de la serie ulam (das un numero y si ies par se divide entre 2 y si es impar se multiplica por 3 y se suma 1, asi hasta llegar a 1 que seria el fin) pero me piden guardas los numeros en un arreglo. los renglones son generados por un random (1  a 5) mientras que las columnas deben ser 70 aunque no todas se usan. El numero a usar tambien es un random (de 2 a 209 A mi me sale si lo imprimo en un print pero cuando intento guardarlo en el arreglo me marca error... dejo el codigo que tengo esperando me puedan ayudar...

```
Random ra=new Random();

int  mat [ ] [ ];
int  ren,col = 0,rrn,r=0,re,c=0;
boolean vr=false;

rrn=2+ra.nextInt(4);
  mat = new int [c ]  [ r ];

  for(ren=0;ren<rrn;ren++)
      {

           for(col=0;vr!=true;col++)
           {
                 re=2+ra.nextInt(19);
                 mat [ren] [col]=re;
                 while(re!=1)
                       { 
                             if(re%2!=0)
                              {
                               re=(re*3)+1;

                              }//fin del if
                            else
                             {
                               re=re/2;

                             }//fin del else
                             mat[ren] [col]=re;
                       }// fin del while 
                 vr=true;
           }//fin del for col
           vr=false;
      }//fin del for ren
    System.out.println( mat [ren][col]+" : ");
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedo comentarte, pero de momento veo que el error sería ArrayIndexBoundsException (?) Postealo si es así.

```
mat = new int [c ]  [ r ];
```

Estas creando el Array a 0 - 0 ya que col = 0 y r = 0. Por lo tanto cuando intentas dar la segunda vuelta

```
mat [ren] [col]=re; // No existe ya has creado el array solo para 0 - 0
```

Postea el error si puedes. Gracias !

Comment: gracias bro, lo pude hacer, modifique el campo del arreglo y si ya me corrio bien. Gracias